# How to redirect file to download outside XAMPP htdocs without using any framework?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have put a download button in my web application. Currently, I am having problem to redirect the download button outside XAMPP root folder (eg: in D drive).

Below is my code that i use for the download button.(I do not change the code yet)

```
<form action="code4.php?file_id=.\files<?php echo $row['path']?>.nwd" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="download_btn" class="btn btn-success"> Download </button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: cannot download file outside root folder

Comment: Simply create a junction point (symlink) from inside the XAMPP docroot to anywhere outside it.